# Допустима ли такая запись?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Допустима ли такая запись?

```
jQuery("#menu>a[href=http://www.lightelite.ca/#home]")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
$("#menu>a[href='http://www.lightelite.ca/#home']")
```

или

```
$('#menu>a[href="http://www.lightelite.ca/#home"]')
```

Иначе парсер не сможет разобрать строку

---

А в целом ориентир на целый Url делать не стоит. Возможно лучше ориентироваться просто на `location.hash` или добавлять **[data-*](http://htmlbook.ru/samouchitel-html5/atributy-data)** атрибут в ссылку и ориентироваться на него

Comment: Эммм, даже интересно стало чем эти варианты отличаются от изначального (и чем они друг от друга отличаются (и почему нет пары вариантов с ` xDD)). И наверное стоило бы расшифровать про `data-*`